# Merge two pandas dataframes that have slightly different values on the column which is being merged

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I merge two data frames when the column has a slight offset than the column I am merging to?

df1 =

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

df2 =

| col1 | col3 |
| --- | --- |
| 1.01 | d |
| 2 | e |
| 2.95 | f |

so, the merged column would end up like this even though the values in col1 are slightly different.

df_merge =

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | d |
| 2 | b | e |
| 3 | c | f |

I have seen scenarios like this where "col1" is a string, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do this with something like `pandas.merge()` in the scenario where there is slight numerical offset (e.g +/- 0.05).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets do [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `tolerance` parameter

```
pd.merge_asof(
    df1.astype({'col1': 'float'}).sort_values('col1'), 
    df2.sort_values('col1'), 
    on='col1', 
    direction='nearest', 
    tolerance=.05
)
```

---

```
   col1 col2 col3
0   1.0    a    d
1   2.0    b    e
2   3.0    c    f
```

PS: if the dataframes are already sorted on `col1` then there is no need to sort again.